# Pass PHP array through xhr request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm wondering how I can pass a PHP form array through a XHR request. I'm building an RESTful API for processing Symfony2 forms. Some form elements have to be filled in with creepy data like:

```
foo_form[bar][] = 1
foo_form[bar][] = 2
```

My question is, how I can send this through a XHR request in a JS library.

```
var client = FooHttpClient(options);

var data = {
    'foo_form[bar][]' : 1,
    'foo_form[bar][]' : 2
};

client.send(data);
```

The problem here is, that the first data value `(foo_form[bar][] = 1)` will be overriden by the second value.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Greetings,

--Marc

Comment: What is `FooHttpClient`? Answer to your question strongly depends on its xhr implementation.

Comment: Well, to be concrete, in this case its the Titanium API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `data` passed to `send` will be transformed to urlencoded POST data, try using JavaScript object structure:

```
var data = {
    "foo_form": {
        "bar": [1,2]
    }
};
```

If the API does not handle multiple levels of object/arrays, you can still use your attempt, but add numerical indexes to an array:

```
var data = {
    'foo_form[bar][0]' : 1,
    'foo_form[bar][1]' : 2
};
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides the `json_encode()` function specifically for this.

`json_encode()` converts a PHP array or object structure into a JSON string. JSON is a serialised data format which is directly compatible with Javascript (JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation).

Once the JSON string is in your Javascript code, you can decode it using `JSON.parse()` to convert it into a JS object. (note, older browsers - eg IE6 - do not support this, so you may need to use a library to parse it (it is possible that your `FooHttpClient` provides this functionality built-in; we don't know enough about `FooHttpClient` from the question to help you with that though).

PHP also has a `json_decode()` function to convert a valid JSON string back into a PHP array, so you can also send JSON data back from JS to your PHP program.

Virtually all languages have JSON encode/decode functionality, so JSON is a good data format for cross-language communication.

Comment: Hm...maybe I used the wrong words for describing my problem. The second param will be overriding by the first. 

    var json = '{"foo_form[bar][]" : 1, "foo_form[bar][]" : 2}';
    var bar = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(bar); // Object { foo_form[bar][]=2} 
                      // First value is missing

Answer (score 0):

Join the array and turn it into a comma separated list where you can then pass it as a URL param. Then use GET on the other side and explode the list back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
{'foo_form[bar][]' : 1},
{'foo_form[bar][]' : 2}
];   //array of json objects
```

Comment: Whoa...this looks nice. I'll try this. Thank you.